# Get the max. length of a field

Tags: apex, describefieldresult

If somebody wants to get the maximum length of a field, then he has to use below code:

```
integer fieldLength = Schema.SObjectType.CustObj__c.fields.CustField__c.getLength();
```

But, my question is, whether is this applibale to both Text and Number field or only Text Field ?

Answer (score 5):

The `getLength()` is for the string fields, If you want to get a number of digits you need to use `getDigits()` method of the `DescribeFieldResult` class.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = CustObj__c.CustField__c.getDescribe();

if(F.getType() == 'String')
    // Here get the length of the string field

if(F.getType() == 'Integer')
    // Only integers
```

Here you can read more about it: [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getLength)

Comment: The getLength() method always returns a max of 40 even if the field has a max of 255. Does anyone know the reason for this? And how to get the _actual_ field length when longer than 40 chars???